# Ошибка в bash скрипте при инсталяции deb пакета

Tags: bash

Занимаюсь созданием deb пакета. Данный скрипт завершается ошибкой как при инсталировании самого пакета, так и при отдельном запуске. Помогите найти ошибку в коде. Права на файл -rwxr-xr-x

```
#!/bin/bash -e
echo "preinst"
mkdir /etc/monreal/
mkdir /etc/monreal/html/
mkdir /etc/monreal/logs/
return 0
```

Вывод ошибки

```
user@1dev-crypt03:~$ ./test/preinst
: недопустимый параметр
```

Comment: программа *linux* не имеет отношения к програмее *bash*. от слова совсем. потому метку убрал. ну и метка bash подразумевает, что речь идёт про конкретную реализацию posix-совместимой оболочки под названием bash, а метка shell подразумевает, что речь идёт о posix-совместимых оболочках вообще. т.е., в данном случае, они противоречат друг другу.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, `shell` является надмножеством по отношению к `bash`. Вполне могут сосуществовать вместе. Почитайте, что ли, определения... https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Подмножество

Answer (score 3):

воспроизводится элементарно. достаточно изменить символы окончания строк на dos-овские.

---

приступим:

```
$ echo '#!/bin/bash -e' > файл
$ echo 'echo ok' >> файл
$ chmod +x файл
```

пока корректно работает:

```
$ ./файл 
ok
```

а теперь сделаем то же самое, что и автор вопроса — заменим окончания строк на некорректные:

```
$ unix2dos файл
unix2dos: converting file файл to DOS format...
```

и получим ту же ошибку:

```
$ ./файл 
: invalid option
```

насмотревшись на неё, вернём всё назад:

```
$ dos2unix файл 
dos2unix: converting file файл to Unix format...
$ ./файл 
ok
```

ну, ок…

Comment: у меня на centOS 6,5 при запуске dos2unix бывали случаи удаления оригинального файла, т.е. файл оказывался пустым при вызове не из каталога `dos2unix /абсолютный путь`, начал использовать просто sed, `sed -i 's/\r//g' файл` убрать возврат каретки, `sed -i 's/$/\r/g'` установить возврат каретки.